# How to draw text view with 2 Colors in android

Tags: android, user-interface, textview

I want to draw text view with 2 color like the text in this link [here](http://i120.photobucket.com/albums/o164/mith1912/Untitled-1.jpg).

Anyone can show me how to do?

Comment: What do you mean with "draw text" - on a canvas or just in a TextView ?

Comment: I want to draw text in a Text View . Now my implement is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple asnwer is to override `onDraw()` method, draw your test with black color and create a paint and set to it an xfermode

```
 paint.setXfermode(new AvoidXfermode(Color.BLACK, 255, AvoidXfermode.Mode.TARGET))
 paint.setColor(R.color.red);
```

and draw on canvas a rectangle with the desired width using this paint

Comment: Thanks for your support

 I 've followed your suggestion but result is not like my expectation

, my result is

[here](http://s120.photobucket.com/albums/o164/mith1912/?action=view&current=Screenshot2012-01-13at60753PM.png)      Please help me , i am a newbie

Comment: fill all your canvas with white, draw your text with black and create a new paint like in my source code and draw a rectangle in your canvas using this paint

Comment: Thank you very much, I can do this. your solution is very simple and useful.:)

Answer (score 3):

See SpannedString & SpannedStringBuilder & ColorSpan

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannedString.html